# Randomised Brute Forcer

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, brute-force

For educational purposes, I made a simple Brute Forcer. Due to how it works though, the likelihood of me getting results early on is incredibly slim. That said, I would like to randomise the results without getting duplicates and without slowing it down drastically.

The code at the moment:

```
from threading import Thread

charset = (
        'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
        '1234567890'
        'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
)

def recurse(width, position, base_string):
    for i in range(len(charset)):
        if position < (width - 1):
            Thread(target=recurse(width, position+1,base_string+charset[i])).start()
        Thread(target=write_content(base_string+charset[i]+'\n')).start()

def write_content(content):
    with open('permutations', 'a+') as f:
            f.write(content)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    recurse(15,0,'')
```

My goal is to get my results randomized. So instead of:

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
...
cbc
cca
ccb
ccc
```

I'd get something along the lines of:

```
aaa
bac
cba
abc
bbc
ccc
...
```

How would I go about this? I've been thinking about it for some time and just can't work it out.

Also, what language would process this the fastest?

Answer (score 0):

You have charset, a list of characters you want to choose from, so why not select a random character from this set? Using python's [random](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)
module should let you do this fairly easily.

If you select a random index in the string charset at each step, it should have the effect you are looking for.

Edit: I realised I didn't answer the second part of your question - I would suggest creating a list of strings which have been checked. After each attempt (ie. after each randomly generated string), you could add the string to said list. Then, when you generate a new string, check it against this list to ensure it has not been used again.

If you add the strings to the 'used' list in such a way that it is sorted (like an [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)), you can use a to speed this up. If you follow these steps, you should save a lot of time for larger length strings/longer sets of checks.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the [itertools module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) along with the [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

```
chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
ps = [p for p in itertools.permutations(chars, 3)]
random.shuffle(ps)
```

This will generate all permutations of length 3, so as your length grows, it will be significantly slower. Length 3 was almost instant on my machine, length
5 generated a memory error :-)

Comment: Go on... What is in the itertools module that can yield randomly ordered results with no repeats?

Comment: @Kevin `seq = [''.join(item) for item in itertools.product('ABC', repeat=2)]; random.shuffle(seq)` gives a shuffled list of `['AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BB', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB', 'CC']`